# A question about "small" uncountable cardinal numbers

Tags: set-theory

If $X$ denotes a set, let $C(X)$ denote its cardinal number and let $P(X)$ denote its power set. There is a school of thought which considers any set having the cardinal number $C(P(\mathbb{R}))$—where $\mathbb{R}$ denotes the set of real numbers—to be too large for the intuition to grasp. This school mantains that in almost all branches of mathematics except set theory itself, there is no need to require the existence of any set whose cardinal number is greater than $C(\mathbb{R})$.

Although this viewpoint sounds plausible, I wonder whether it might lead to problems in Measure Theory. Suppose one wants to prove in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that there  exist sets of real numbers which are not Lebesgue measurable. Does there exist any set $M$, definable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, which satisfies the following conditions:

1. $M$ is a subset of $P(\mathbb{R})$,
2. It is provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that at least one element of $M$ is *not* Lebesgue measurable, and
3. The cardinal number of $M$ is $C(\mathbb{R})$?

I know a number of examples of sets—definable in ZFC—that satisfy (1) and (2), but none of them also satisfies (3).

Comment: I conjecture there's a typo in the question.  As it stands, the set of open intervals in R satisfies the stated conditions.

Comment: Would you like to share which school of thought (or who) claims that cardinals bigger than $2^{\omega}$ are not required in any field of mathematics except set theory itself?

Comment: To extend @Andreas comment, the Borel sets satisfy the three requirements.

Comment: To extend my comment in another direction, use the singletons.

Comment: Should (2) say "...at least one element of $M$ is _not_ Lebesgue measurable"?

Comment: @Trevor Wilson: You are right. I left out the "not" in condition (2) and didn't even notice it. My question without the "not" is trivial but I am afraid that, if I try to fix it, I will batch the thing up even more. I have a lot of trouble trying to correct mistakes when I post questions in MATHOVERFLOW. Please accept my apologies for this booboo.

Comment: @GarabedGulbenkian I made that correction and improved the formatting a bit.  A minor point is that (I think) the phrase "does there exist any set $M$, definable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, which satisfies the following conditions..." should be replaced with "does there exist any formula $\varphi(x)$ such that it is provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that the set $M = \{A \subset \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) : \varphi(A)\}$ satisfies the following conditions...."  (The former phrasing is not quite precise.)  Then you can remove the phrase "it is provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that" from condition (2).

Comment: @Christoph-SimonSenjak There are only $|\mathbb{R}|$ many continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, although I'm not sure I understand the philosophical motivation.  If we change (3) to say that $M$ has cardinality _strictly_ less than $\mathbb{R}$, then the answer is no, and this already seems not entirely trivial.

Comment: Garabed: Isn't the question still trivial after the edit? Pick your favorite non-measurable set S, say in (0,1), and consider the its unions with Borel sets of $(-\infty,0]\cup[1,\infty)$.
@TrevorWilson: Eventhough, that example fails to demonstrate it, I think the point Christoph was trying to make was that you do need sets of size greater than continuum (or power set of continuum) in many fields of mathematics. Right now, it seems that above mentioned school of thought refuses to believe in sigma algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets.

Comment: Wait, nowhere you require $M$ to be closed under countable unions and complements. In that case, pick any non-measurable set $A$, then consider $\{A\}\cup\{\{r\}\mid r\in\Bbb R\}$. @Trevor: How does that make it less trivial? $\{A\}$ for any non-measurable set $A$ is of size $<\frak c$.

Comment: @Burak $M$ is required to be _definable_.  There are models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ where every definable set of reals is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: @Asaf See my comment to Burak.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have heard the philosophical premiss of the question in serious mathematical discussions. I bet it wouldn't be that hard to find an example in the literature though I'm afraid it's been so long I don't recall a precise instance.

Comment: @TrevorWilson: I seem to have overlooked the definability requirement twice, both in the original question and the edited one. In that case, I guess the answer (consistently) can be trivially yes, using a global definable well ordering to choose a fixed non-measurable set and construct the examples given above. Also, can you give some reference to the fact in your last comment for me to check out how those models look like?

Comment: @Burak I don't have a reference, but my idea was the following:  Start with a model of ZF plus DC plus "every set of reals is Lebesgue measurable."  Moreover assume that the generic extension $V[G]$ by $\text{Col}(\omega_1,\mathbb{R})$ satisfies AC.  Then in $V[G]$ every definable set of reals is Lebesgue measurable (by homogeneity) and moreover if $M$ is a definable subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ containing a non-Lebesgue measurable set $A$, then $M$ contains uncountably many non-Lebesgue measurable sets...

Comment: ...to see this, let $A = \tau_G$ be a non-Lebesgue measurable element of $M$ and let $p$ be a condition forcing this.  Then we can find a perfect tree of conditions extending $p$ and forcing $\tau$ to take different values.  By countable closure there is a condition extending each branch.  This gives us continuum many sets of reals with the desired properties that $A$ has.

Comment: @TrevorWilson I've been thinking about that model also (but possibly collapsing larger cardinals), but I want to prove the opposite answer. Namely, I don't think one will be able to arrange in the general case that the definable set of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ will have *exactly*  $\frak{c}$ members, as required, if it has a non-measurable member. I suspect that if ZFC is consistent, then there is no definition with all the OP's properties.

Comment: Some of the comments above seem to miscontrue the issue of the definability of $M$, that is, of the *family* of sets of reals, with the definability of the *elements* of $M$, that is, with the definability of particular sets of reals. Obviously the collection of all non-measurable sets of a reals is a definable family of sets of reals, and ZFC proves that it is uncountable and furthermore that it has non-measurable elements, but this family does not have size $\frak{c}$, but rather $2^{\frak{c}}$, which although uncountable, does not satisfy (3).

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Why can't we say "the collection M of sets of reals all of which differ from the first non-Lebesgue measurable set by a singleton" in L?

Comment: What is the "first non-measurable set"? If you mean the "L-least non-measurable set in L", then it is consistent with ZFC that this set is countable, since it is consistent that there are only countable many reals in L, and in such a model of ZFC, all your sets in M will be countable and hence ZFC will not prove that your M contains a non-measurable set.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins At the risk of stating the obvious, I might point out that if you can get a definable set $M$ of non-Lebesgue measurable sets with $\le \mathfrak{c}$ members, then you can get such an $M$ with exactly $\mathfrak{c}$ members.  So the hard part in getting a "yes" answer would be to make $M$ small.  And I agree with you that this probably can't be done; I considered the observation that $M$ can't be "too small" (_i.e._ it is consistent that there is no countable such $M$) as a partial result in this direction.

Comment: @Trevor Wilson: Sorry, my mistake. Deleted the comment.

Comment: @Burak: The "school of thought" is just an extreme version of the views expressed by George Boolos in the article "Must we believe in Set Theory" which appears in the book "Between Logic and Intuition" edited by Gila Sher and Richard Tieszen. Boolos questions whether the power set of a large set is an intuitively clear notion. One then faces the question of how far up the set theoretic hierarchy one really needs to go to prove the theorems of most branches of mathematics-other than set theory itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a positive answer, unfortunately it is predicated on a hypothesis which is widely believed to be false: that the existence of inaccessible cardinals is inconsistent with ZFC. Stated in a more digestible manner, the argument below shows that some large cardinal hypotheses are necessary to obtain a negative answer to the question.

Let $V$ be a model of $ZFC$, let $\mathfrak{c}^V$ denote the cardinality of the continuum in $V$ and let $\aleph_1^V$ denote the first uncountable ordinal in $V$. In $L$, $\aleph_1^V$ must be an uncountable regular cardinal and, since there aren't any inaccessible cardinals, it must be a successor cardinal. Let $\kappa$ denote the cardinal in $L$ such that $(\kappa^+)^L = \aleph_1^V$; note that $\kappa$ is definable in $V$. In $V$, $\kappa$ is countable, so there are reals $r$ in $V$ such that $\kappa$ is countable in $L[r]$ and for such reals we necessarily have $\aleph_1^{L[r]} = \aleph_1^V$. Let $K$ be the set of all reals such that $\aleph_1^{L[r]} = \aleph_1^V$; note that $K$ is definable in $V$ and $K$ has size $\mathfrak{c}^V$. For each $r \in K$, $X_r = \mathbb{R}^{L[r]}$ is a set of reals with a canonical wellordering of order type $\aleph_1^{L[r]} = \aleph_1^{V}$.

Following Raisonnier [*A mathematical proof of S. Shelah's theorem on the measure problem and related results*, Israel J. Math. 48 (1984), no. 1, 48–56; [MR0768265](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=768265); [DOI:10.1007/BF02760523](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02760523)], we can associate to each $r \in K$ a filter $F_r$ and a collection of sets $\mathcal{H}_r$ of size at most $\mathfrak{c}^V$ such that either $F_r$ is rapid and hence not measurable, or at least one element of $\mathcal{H}_r$ is not measurable. (The set $\mathcal{H}_r$ consists of all sets that Raisonnier denotes $\tilde{H}(X_r)$. These are associated to $G_\delta$ sets $H \subseteq \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ with null sections; since there are continuum many such $G_\delta$ sets, it follows that $|\mathcal{H}_r| \leq \mathfrak{c}^V$.)

Putting all this together, under the unlikely assumption that inaccessible cardinals provably do not exist in ZFC, in any model $V$ of ZFC, the definable set $$\{F_r : r \in K\} \cup \bigcup_{r \in K} \mathcal{H}_r$$ has size $\mathfrak{c}^V$ and it must contain a non measurable set.

Comment: As suggested in comments to the question, it seems likely that Solovay's construction assuming the existence of inaccessible cardinals (or perhaps larger cardinals) could be adapted to give a model where no such definable sets exists. The argument above then simply shows that large cardinal hypotheses are indeed necessary for this.

Comment: To mitigate the shock of the prefacing sentence, here's an alternative formulation for the additional axiom "There are no inaccessible cardinals in $L$".

Comment: @AsafKaragila: But that's equivalent. The way I'm reading the question, a positive answer needs to show that every model $V$ of ZFC has such a definable family. It's true I only use that there are no inaccessibles in $L^V$ but this is true for all $V$ if and only if ZFC proves that there are no inaccessible cardinals.

Comment: Of course. But it makes the rest of the answer somewhat easier to swallow.

Comment: @Trevor Wilson: Thanks alot for editing my question. You are right that my phrase "definable in ZFC" is not precise, but I could not figure out how to assemble an alphabet of symbols to represent the kind of monadic formula that you provided.

Comment: @Garabed: This is not the first time I've seen you post comments to answers when you should have posted them on the question, and vice versa. You should try and pay slightly closer attention as to where you're posting the comment -- question, or answer (and which answer, too). Otherwise the odds of the intended recipients seeing the comments and replying are lower, and it's likely they will see it at a later time if they do see it.

Answer (score 10):

This is independent. See: *Harvey Friedman*, [**On definability of nonmeasurable sets**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1980-051-3), *Canad. J. Math.* **32** (1980), no. 3, 653--656.

Comment: Great! If I'm reading correctly, the answer to the question is, "no" assuming the consistency of inaccessible cardinals with ZFC and (following my answer) "yes" if inaccessible cardinals are inconsistent with ZFC.

Comment: I slightly edited your post to include a link (using the `\cite` plugin, courtesy of Scott Morrison).

Comment: The consistency of "there is such a definable collection" is relatively easy because everything is definable in L.